# access based share enum not working as expected

Tags: samba, samba4, arch-linux

On a long-term (2years) Arch Linux server, I am running a small samba configuration with several shares.
I would like users to only see the shares which they have access to - which is why I am using the "access based share enum = yes" configuration option (see [smb.conf(5)](https://man.archlinux.org/man/smb.conf.5.en#:%7E:text=access%20based%20share%20enum%20(S)) )

This was working as expected until samba 4.16 arrived (I admit that I cannot prove that 4.16 changed that, but it does look like it).
The behaviour since 4.16 is that **all shares are invisible, even though I can still access them.**

I have stripped down my smb.conf to a minimum version with just one share, the problem persists.
Here is the output of testparm smb.conf:

```
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
Loaded services file OK.
Weak crypto is allowed

Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE

Press enter to see a dump of your service definitions

# Global parameters
[global]
        disable spoolss = Yes
        dns proxy = No
        interfaces = 192.168.16.10/24
        load printers = No
        logging = systemd
        printcap name = /dev/null
        server role = standalone server
        server string = rathernotsay
        show add printer wizard = No
        idmap config * : backend = tdb
        hosts allow = 192.168.14. 192.168.16. 192.168.17. 10.1. 127.
        printing = bsd


[temp]
        access based share enum = Yes
        comment = temporary files
        create mask = 0770
        directory mask = 02770
        force create mode = 0660
        force directory mode = 02770
        path = /mnt/subvol_mounts/samba/temp
        read only = No
        valid users = +samba_temp
        vfs objects = btrfs
```

I am grateful for any help on this topic.
Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There was a regression related to reading the share_info.tdb file. It was fixed a few weeks ago so it should show up in the 4.16.9 and 4.17.5 releases.

https://bugzilla.samba.org/show_bug.cgi?id=15265

While I wouldn't recommend it in a production system I can confirm that chmod 666 on share_info.tdb does in fact restore the expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

> The behavior since 4.16 is that all shares are invisible, even though
> I can still access them.

Hello,
I'm experiencing the exact same thing here. I can confirm this behavior occurs with the 4.16.5 (I've upgraded from 4.15.9 to 4.16.5)
It might be a desired behavior but is there a way of getting the old behavior back?

Thanks